# google map api: how to show text beside the marker?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[image: the position description(blue words)]

How to show the text beside the marker? just like the blue words. 
It's not title or the info window.

Comment: I don't think that blue text belongs to the marker but rather to the POI under it. Still you can have a look at this library: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.10/examples/basic.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the answer,use MapLabel.

[MapLabel demo](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/maplabel/examples/maplabel.html)